# Garrys Mod ULX if user is group then

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

Basically I am trying to use ULX in Garrys mod and have a file check if the user is VIP or staff that it will give them a weapon as soon as it notices the weapon being `weapon_physgun`. This would need to check over and over so when a player joins or a player donates and gets switched to VIP it will give them the custom weapon.

At this time I have no code.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you also check ULX with `ply:GetUserGroup()`?

Anyway, here's how I would do it:

```
function checkranks(ply)
    if (ply:GetUserGroup() == "yourgroup") then
        ply:Give("weapon")
    end
end
```

If you would like to do it on the player's first spawn, then do:

```
hook.Add( "PlayerInitalSpawn", "Check Ranks", checkranks)
```

Answer (score 1):

In ULX, you must check the user's usergroup via table.

Here's an example/What it should be:

```
function checkULX(ply)
    if table.HasValue({"superadmin", "admin"}, ply:GetNWString("usergroup")) then
        ply:Give("crowbar")
    end
end
```

This would give the player a crowbar if they are in the ULX group "superadmin" or "admin" when the function is called.